# Storing actual files in cache

Tags: java, file, caching, guava, in-memory

I have Microsoft Office files which I need to store in Google Guava cache. The key will be fileid and the value will be actual word document. I have that word document in the ByteArrayOutput stream but storing ByteArrayOutput stream is not a good idea. Any other thought ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to cache the binary content you could write the outputstream to a byte array and cache that array, but I would recommend to try the solution from Peter Lawrey first. The only performance penality would be that you need to read the file through the OS, but it is hard to image that, you do so many operations that this would be a problem.

Comment: Liked that - will try that out.

Answer (score 0):

The OSes disk cache already caches in files in memory that you might like to use later. I would make use of that first.  This means all you need to cache is meta data like files name

Comment: It is an web application running on a server which is first making use of a third party jar file which dynamically generates this word document and creates and output stream. So this won't be available in OS disk cache. Won't work in this situations but in others might. I will have to try out option by Casey, I guess. Converting outputstream to bytearray and then storing bytearray. Please let me know if above not true.